# iBeacon and Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

i'm developing an iOS application and i'm using beacons.

I've a problem. I'm at the beginning of the development, so I only have my appdelegate. In appdelegate.m I have initialized like so

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"8AEFB031-6C32-486F-825B-E26FA193487D"];
    CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid
                                                                identifier:@"Region"];

    if ([CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"I'm looking for a beacon");
        [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Device doesn't support beacons ranging");
    }

    return YES;
}
```

and then I wrote two delegate methods

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"EXIT");
}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"ENTER");
}
```

but they never get called!!! What's the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you RANGE but you never MONITOR the regions.

Ranging for beacons will only call: 
 `locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:`

The methods enterRegion/exitRegion you want are for monitoring only. So call: 
`- (void)startMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region`

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why there are not calling but this is how we can handle beacons...

```
- (void)createBeaconRegion
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;

NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"8AEFB031-6C32-486F-825B-E26FA193487D"];
CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid
                                                            identifier:@"Region"];

if ([CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]])
{
    NSLog(@"I'm looking for a beacon");
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Device doesn't support beacons ranging");
}
}

- (void)turnOnRanging
{
    NSLog(@"Turning on ranging...");

    if (![CLLocationManager isRangingAvailable]) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't turn on ranging: Ranging is not available.");
        self.rangingSwitch.on = NO;
        return;
    }

    if (self.locationManager.rangedRegions.count > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Didn't turn on ranging: Ranging already on.");
        return;
    }

    [self createBeaconRegion];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];

    NSLog(@"Ranging turned on for region: %@.", self.beaconRegion);
}


- (void)startRangingForBeacons
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    self.detectedBeacons = [NSArray array];

    [self turnOnRanging];
}

- (void)stopRangingForBeacons
{
    if (self.locationManager.rangedRegions.count == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Didn't turn off ranging: Ranging already off.");
        return;
    }

    [self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
 NSLog(@"Turned off ranging.");
}
```

You can refer the entire sample project using below link

https://github.com/nicktoumpelis/HiBeacons

That uses to display Beacons..

Hope it helps you....!